# Remote points in $\beta X$

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, gn.general-topology, stone-cech-compactification

It is known that in general convergence by sequences is not enough to account for all points in $\beta X \setminus X$, where $\beta X$ refers to the Stone-Cech compactification of a topological space $X$, and ultrafilters are needed. In fact, if $X$ is completely regular and Hausdorff, there are lots of points in $\beta X$ which are not the limits in $\beta X$ of any discrete subset of $X$ and these are called the "remote points" of $\beta X$. My question is, is it known whether the set of remote points in $\beta X$ is $F_\sigma$? Or are there known sufficient conditions on $X$ such that the set of remote points become $F_\sigma$? Thanks.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1443886/remote-points-in-beta-x

Comment: When you order food, how many places do you call simultaneously? Just one. Right? When you ask a question online, you should ask it in *one* place.